# simple code with plain js : addEventListener doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

i just wanted to make a test, i'm used to work on jQuery but not on "plain" javascript, i tried to bind this event, but i've got no answer from  the event, i just created a link and a script tag in the html code, with :

> var li = document.getElementById('first');
>               li.addEventListener('onMouseover', function(){
>                   alert('ok');
>               })

Can you please tell me what is wrong with it? i don't see the mistake.
Thanks

Comment: try `mouseover`, all lowercase?

Comment: thanks, but i don't know why, the code doesn't respond. it responds with a simple alert('ok') though, but nothing with onmouseover... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to drop the "on" part for `addEventListener()`. Second, the event name needs to be all lower case. Third, you were missing the third parameter, which is Boolean indicating whether to handle the event in the capturing phase rather than the bubbling phase (if in doubt, use `false`).

The other issue you need to consider is that IE <= 8 does not support `addEventListener()`, so you need to include an IE-specific fallback using the proprietary [`attachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

With all this, your example becomes:

```
var li = document.getElementById('first');
if (typeof li.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    li.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        alert('ok');
    }, false);
} else if (typeof li.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    li.attachEvent('onmouseover', function() {
        alert('ok');
    });
}
```

The easiest cross-browser solution is the so-called DOM0 method, using the element's `onmouseover` property. However, this has the disadvantage of only allowing one event listener per event per element and is therefore potentially susceptible to being overridden by other code.

```
li.onmouseover = function() {
    alert('ok');
};
```

Comment: Thanks, as i said to the previous post, i've got an error from Firebug, telling me that the variable is "null"... i'm on Mac - chrome or Safari, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Paul: Which variable? `li`? If so, the problem is that there is no element with the ID `first` in the document. If there is such an element, then if your script is running before the element appears in the document's HTML, the element won't have been created at the point the script runs.

Comment: thanks for your answer, well all of this makes sense, but it still doesn't want. Can you try in an html editor? i've just used a div, a link, and a simple onmouseover (also i tried with addEventListener), but the event won't be triggered : code<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> var lis = document.getElementById('first'); lis.onmouseover = function() { alert('yo'); }; </script> </head> <body> <div id="first"><a href="#">first</a></div> </body> </html>code

Comment: @Paul: That's exactly the problem I was describing. You need to wait until the element is in the document. You can do this using the load event of the window. For example: `window.onload = function() { var lis = document.getElementById('first'); lis.onmouseover = function() { alert('yo'); }; };`

Comment: ALright! thanks, lol, i don't think about that in jQuery i write the document.ready stuff automatically, i forgot we need it also in js. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the handler function directly to the `onmouseover` property of the selected element in the DOM:

```
var lis = document.getElementById('first');
lis.onmouseover = function() {
    alert('yo');
};
```

On jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/YMGAy/

Docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmouseover

**Edit:**
Here it is too using `addEventListener`...

```
li = document.getElementById('first');
li.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    alert('ok');
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/7FvZ7/
You were missing the last argument to `addEventListener` (for `useCapture`)

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work on my computer ! i copied exactly the same code as the on jsFiddle, can you try to write it inside a html page?

Comment: Which jsFiddle? Also, what browser are you using?  See the notes on IE in the `element.addEventListener` docs.  It's easiest to avoid addEventListener if possible since you don't have to worry about handling IE then.

Comment: hi, both jsFiddle actually, firebug tells me the variable is "null" (and it shows me the line with addEventListener), but why? with both exemples, i've got the same result... (i'm on mac - chrome or Firefox)